# how to store results of ./a.out to a text file

Tags: c, linux, shell, terminal

I am wondering if there is any way to store the results of my program into a text file.  I know you can just do something like ./a.out > output.txt but for my program, after I type ./a.out I am prompted again for TIME: where I put in the amount of time, and then upon hitting enter the algorithm is performed and the results are output.

The program outputs a stage for a period of time, and basically my output looks like this:

```
time 0:00 stage 1

time 0:05 stage 1

...

time 2:05 stage 2
```

How can I get the output stored into a text file?

Comment: It is a very **bad habit to** actually **call your program binary `a.out`**. You can compile a single-file source file `single.c` with `gcc -Wall -g single.c -o singleprog` then run `./singleprog` (of course, use more appropriate names). For a many source files program, learn to use `make` or some other builder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So redirect the input as well:

`./a.out < input.txt > output.txt`

Where `input.txt` contains the amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to print the result to `stderr`

```
fprintf(stderr, "time %d:....");
```

And redirect `stderr` to `output.txt`

```
./myprog 2> output.txt
```

Note: this is a workaround if you don't wish to open a file, I don't like using `stderr` for anything other than errors.

Comment: @sudo_O yes after reading the input we print the output to `stderr` and redirect that, your way requires the user to write all the input to file first

Comment: One of us is missing something here? In your case the user would still be prompted for input everytime?

Comment: @sudo_O yes and that is what was required in the first place

Comment: I disagree, printing non-errors to `stderr` is bad practice, I think redirecting input is a better lesson here, would say this more of a `hack`, anyway... `+1`

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to pass the TIME parameter as an argument and use ./a.out time > output.txt to output it to a file.

Comment: thx.  i used sudo_O's method but I will try this as well. u guys rock.  i gave u a up :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is what sudo_O told you (it works in every os)

```
./a.out <in.txt >out.txt.
```

If you want to do this in C, use freopen() (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen/)

```
 freopen ("myoutput.txt","w",stdout);
 freopen ("myinput.txt","r",stdin);
```

This redirects stdout to myoutput.txt, so all printfs goes to "myoutput.txt". 
Also redirects stdin to myinput.txt, so all scanfs are reading from "myinput.txt".